# PostgreSQL: psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "INSERT"

Tags: postgresql

Есть у меня такой запрос:

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified
FROM source.table
WHERE target.table.collect_project_id != source.table.projects.id
AND (source.table.projects.created > getdate() - interval '30 minutes' OR source.table.projects.modified > getdate() - interval '30 minutes'))
INSERT INTO target.table (
            collect_project_id,
            project_number,
            project_name,
            connect_project_id,
            project_desc,
            project_type,
            project_status,
            project_path,
            language_code,
            country_code,
            timezone,
            date_created,
            date_updated
            )
            SELECT
            id,
            number,
            name,
            connect_project_id,
            description,
            type,
            status,
            path,
            language,
            country,
            timezone,
            created,
            modified
            FROM temp;
```

Но что-то ругается на него интерпретатор, но я в упор не могу понять где ошибся...

Comment: WITH - это часть SELECT, а не INSERT. Так что `INSERT .. WITH .. SELECT ..`

Comment: Я сейчас Вас не понял, извините. Вот читаю документацию: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-insert.html - WITH идет вначале.

Comment: Формально - оба варианта, конечно, правильны. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=0ac5352848f5755beba0d2daf1389cdc Но с точки зрения логики (по крайне мере для меня лично - впрочем, не настаиваю) лучше всё же использовать `INSERT .. WITH .. SELECT ..`. Вот если в CTE находится DML с RETURNING (как в примере по ссылке) - тогда другое дело. *что-то ругается на него интерпретатор, но я в упор не могу понять где ошибся...* А сообщение об ошибке-то мы когда-нить увидим?